# how to call c# extension method in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, extension-methods

I have an Extension method `ToShamsi` for class `DateTime` in Asp.net Core.

and I need use this extension method in JQuery.

How should I do this?
Assume that I have a user and then I can call this extension method in view like this:

```
@user.RegisterDate.ToShamsi();
```

How should I use above code in JQuery like this?
user,get by Ajax:

```
$("#tableBody").append("<tr><td>" +
         user.RegisterDate+                        
         "</td></tr>" );
```

above code is ok but i wants covert date to shamsi:

```
$("#tableBody").append("<tr><td>" +
         user.RegisterDate.ToShamsi()+                        
         "</td></tr>" );
```

Comment: Do you mean to send a request to an asp.net server?

Comment: Is user declared in js on the browser or in c#  e.g. in Razor?

Comment: user get by Ajax in jquery

Answer (score 2):

Since your extension method is in c# and runs on the server and jquery is client side you have 3 options.

1. Re-implement the logic in your c# code in JavaScript
2. Create an endpoint on your server that you can call from your JS code to return the value you need.
3. Call your extension method when your page is rendered and use the value as necessary

Depending on how your application is architected, one option may make more sense than an other.

Comment: 2a. Include the value in an existing endpoint response. (From comment to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call it in JQuery unless you put your javascript code in your razor code then you can put @user.RegisterDate.ToShamsi() as a parameter.
But I suggest you use a hidden field so you can easily read it in your JQuery code. Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="shamsiDate" value="@user.RegisterDate.ToShamsi()" />
```

Then in your jquery you can say:

```
$("#shamsiDate").val()
```

to read date.